# Not getting notifications of close friend

Tags: facebook

I am unable to get any notification from my close friend on Facebook.
I do not even have a notification button on the top left hand side in my close friend list.

Does anyone have any suggestions why this might be?

Comment: Have you added him to the 'close friend'  list?

Comment: CapsLock should not be your close friend.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get all the updates of a friend on Facebook, try going to their profile page and go to *Friends* in the top right.

There are several options, to see all activity, make sure that

- Get Notifications is checked
- In *Settings* > Select **All updates** (Here you can also choose which updates you get)
- And make sure they are added to your *Close Friends* list